# Laravel Sail install puppeteer chromium

Tags: docker, puppeteer, laravel-sail

I have setup a Laravel Sail environment and I am trying to save a webpage as a pdf using puppeteer.

I am currently using this package to run puppeteer via laravel - https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/browsershot

There requirements section specifies you need to download puppeteer via npm.

Laravel Sail has npm setup so I have installed the puppeteer package but when I try and save a webpage as a screenshot I get the following error

```
The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node '/var/www/html/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.js' '{"url":"https:\/\/google.com","action":"screenshot","options":{"type":"png","path":"\/var\/www\/html\/storage\/app\/public\/screenshot.png","args":[],"viewport":{"width":800,"height":600}}}'" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: /var/www/html/public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (856583). at ChromeLauncher.launch (/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Launcher.js:80:27) at async callChrome (/var/www/html/vendor/spatie/browsershot/bin/browser.js:69:23)
```

Its basically saying it can't find my local version of chromium and I'm not sure how to resolve this, if it wasn't running via docker I could install it locally and point to it but I don't think this is the best solution while using docker.

Comment: I've the same issue... Do you have resolve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to install puppeteer with chromium inside the docker container.
I've currently the exact same setup for Browsershot with Sail.
You'll need to [publish the sail config](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#sail-customization) files which will allow you to edit the docker container.

```sh
sail artisan sail:publish
```

Then you can find the docker files in the root of your Laravel project under `docker/8.0` or `docker/7.4` depending on your PHP version.

Edit the docker file and add the installation command for puppeteer with chromium:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libappindicator3-1 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget libgbm-dev libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    && npm install --global --unsafe-perm puppeteer \
    && chmod -R o+rx /usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium
```

Then rebuild the dockerfile:

```sh
sail build --no-cache
```

Because puppeteer is running in docker we need to disable the sandbox. Bear in mind that docker will be a lot slower to generate the PDF then on your host machine so it might be wise to up the default timeout a bit as well.

```php
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;


Browsershot::html($html)
    ->noSandbox()
    ->timeout(360)
    ->save('your.pdf');
```

Comment: Great solution. But indeed it's a *lot* slower than running this on a Homestead-setup using VirtualBox as VM-provider. Even the smallest VM with only 1GB RAM is working fine - Docker-based generation takes forever and I don't even get the reason for it.

Comment: Worked for me, tks

Comment: Is this the right way of doing that when using sail locally, what is recommended by the Laravel Docs. Or is there a better approach? What needs be modified when deploying to production?

Comment: I am getting a `chmod: cannot access '/usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium': No such file or directory` error occur in the console after running the `sail build --no-cache`. Do you have any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: @johncarter Sounds like the binary of puppeteer has either been renamed or moved since my original answer. You can lookup how to install puppeteer in  docker (ubuntu) and update the `RUN` command accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @KoenHendriks I actually found a solution: https://github.com/spatie/browsershot/discussions/681